# How to deployee report on report server CRM2011

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I created a report in CRM-2011 on-primes using SQL Select Query.
How I deploye it in CRM

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the report(.rdl) into CRM  by going to Reports > New >  [Report Type] Existing File > [browse for rdl] > Name it > Done (unless you want to see it in particular areas then fill out the categorization information).